# Should I store an audio file itself in a BLOB field or should I store its path

Tags: mysql, database, blob

I need to have a catalog of audio files along with some properties of them, like DateCreated, Title, Format etc. I'm expecting to have those files in wav and/or gsm format. The maximum size of a file will be about 10MB. Maximum number of files to be added daily will be around 600. About 25 percent of the records will be erased every 10 days. And 80 percent of the entire records will be deleted every month (according to the approximation). When I query the records I won't need them to be queried with the physical files, rather I'll need their other properties. But then I might want to take a look at a specific file or multiple files , which is when I will pull the audio files themselves.
 Now here's my question: Should I store the audio files in a BLOB column along with their properties in the same table or should I have them in a separate location - this might be a database or just a file directory- and store the path to it? I'm planning to use MySQL, although I'm not quite sure whether it's appropriate for data with such magnitude. So if it's not a good choice could you also suggest another DBMS that'd be more suitable in this particular case.

Comment: save in directory structure on the filesystem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay -- most of the pros/cons apply to audio as well

Comment: @DoSparKot, could you please explain your point of view? WHy do you think this way is better.

Comment: @SalmanA, the link you referenced is indeed a very valuable. But it misses a fact that my database is not going to expand for ever and ever.

Comment: Going by description in question, it sure sounds like a audio-files upload server. That link `Storing Images` is applicable for all media files storage. You'll be keeping meta info in DB anyways.